# What should I do to support testing of in-app purchases for the Windows Store App certification process?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-store

I am building a Windows Store App using HTML5/JS (for Windows 8). I will be adding In-App Purchase capability to the app. I need to provide a way for them to test my app during the certification process but, I don't know what (if anything) I need to do to support this. MSDN and Google/Bing have been no help so far. Any help, guidance, or direction towards resources regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Let me narrate further in case my question is "too broad":

I need to add testing information during the Windows 8 App submission process to inform the testers at Microsoft how to test my app (this includes such things as test credentials for logging into the app). My problem is two fold:

1. I don't know if anything extra is needed on my part for them to adequately test my in-app purchase capabilities
2. If so, what do I need to provide? I'm not finding any information about this. If I need to provide testing information for in-app purchases, what information do they need?

This question is asking about what information (if any) I need to provide to the testers at Microsoft to adequately test the in-app purchase capabilities of my Windows 8 app during the Windows Store App certification process.

Please let me know if you need more details. I'll try to scrape some up.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: This is for Windows -8- Store Apps using HTML5/WinJS. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide anything in my experience. I've had one app pass without anything explicitly called out for testing in-app purchases and I've seen several other apps that also passed without.

Comment: Great thank you Jeremy. That reinforces what I've been hearing from others as well.